# How to view voucher deails like amount and items inside voucher in tally connector library

Tags: connector, tally

I m using tally connecter library i have feched all vouchers successfully but i want particular voucher details like amount items inside voucher

Please help me

I have tried to get all vouchers but did not find any method to get voucher details

In c#

Answer (score 0):

Tally have different structure based on how we enter data.

So, you need to mention fetch list according to voucher view.

let's say you want to get vouchers entered in InvoiceView
use

```c#
var vchs = await _tallyService.GetVouchersAsync<Voucher>(new RequestOptions()
{
    FromDate = new(2009, 4, 1),
    FetchList = Constants.Voucher.InvoiceViewFetchList.All,
    Filters = new List<Filter>() { Constants.Voucher.Filters.ViewTypeFilters.InvoiceVoucherFilter }
   
});
```

if you send fetch list you will get ledger details in Voucher.Ledgers and item details  in Voucher.InventoryAllocations
[image: Ledger Details in Voucher]
[image: InventoryDetails in Voucher]

other views fetch list and filters are already provided in tallyConnector [Constants class.](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector/blob/master/src/TallyConnector.Core/Models/Constants.cs)

also, you can refer tests related to [Fetching Vouchers](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector/blob/master/src/Tests/Services/TallyService/TallyObjects/VoucherTests.cs#L8) to better understand views in voucher.